# Add element to a complex nested collection in swift

Tags: ios, swift, collections

I'm stuck practicing collections in Swift. Actually, I storing data from an online JSON source into dictionaries/arrays. I'm trying to add a new element to the following collection:

```
testDict1: Dictionary<String,Dictionary<Int,Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>>
```

I initialized it with the following elements (it could have been an empty array):

```
testDict1 =  ["fireMagic":[
              0:["name":"Basic attack","damage":100],
              1:["name":"Super attack","damage":200, "lvlReq": 20],
              2:["name":"Mega attack","damage":400, "lvlReq": 40]]]
```

I would like to "update" data within testDict1 (replace and add a new row if needed) from another array such as:

```
testDict1 =  ["fireMagic":[
              0:["name":"Basic attack","damage":100],
              1:["name":"Super attack","damage":200, "lvlReq": 20],
              2:["name":"Mega attack","damage":400, "lvlReq": 40]
              3:["name":"Insane attack","damage":1000, "lvlReq": 60]]]
```

**QUESTION 1**

How can I append the element below to testDict1:

```
3:["name":"Insane attack","damage":1000, "lvlReq": 60] //with "FireMagic" as a key.
```

I'm facing different errors and I can't make it work. I'm sure it must be more complex than the ways I tried and you may have the solution to end my pain :)

**QUESTION 2**

How do I do if I need to add other powers such as "WaterMagic" with the same structure as "FireMagic" in testDict1.

```
testDict1 =  ["fireMagic":[
             0:["name":"Basic attack","damage":100],
             1:["...":"...","...":"..."]],
             ["waterMagic":[
             0:["name":"Basic attack","damage":100]]
```

Thank you in advance for your help in my learning quest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1:

Unsafe:

```
testDict1["fireMagic"]![3] = ["name":"Insane attack","damage":1000, "lvlReq": 60]
```

Safe:

```
if let _ = testDict1["fireMagic"] {
    testDict1["fireMagic"]![3] = ["name":"Insane attack","damage":1000, "lvlReq": 60]
}
```

Safe and simple (thanks @dfri):

```
testDict1["fireMagic"]?[3] = ["name":"Insane attack","damage":1000, "lvlReq": 60]
```

Q2:

```
testDict1["waterMagic"] = [0:["name":"Test attack","damage":100]]
```

---

But I would suggest using arrays, enums and structs instead of dictionaries, it's much simpler to handle, and it's also more safe:

```
enum MagicType {
    case Water
    case Fire
}

struct Magic {
    let magic: MagicType
    let name: String
    let damage: Int
    let lvlReq: Int?
}
```

Create an array of objects:

```
var fireMagics = [Magic(magic: .Fire, name: "Basic attack", damage: 100, lvlReq: nil), Magic(magic: .Fire, name: "Super attack", damage: 200, lvlReq: 20), Magic(magic: .Fire, name: "Mega attack", damage: 100, lvlReq: 40)]
```

Access the objects in the array by index:

```
fireMagics[0]
fireMagics[1]
fireMagics[2]
```

etc.

Add an object to the array:

```
fireMagics.append(Magic(magic: .Fire, name: "Insane attack", damage: 1000, lvlReq: 60))
```

Create a different type of Magic object:

```
var waterMagics = [Magic(magic: .Water, name: "Test attack", damage: 100, lvlReq: nil)]
```

Comment: Since this is a new user asking, it's possibly appropriate to include a safe alternative in Q1 answer above, as contrast to using the forced-unwrapping (/explain the dangers using this approach).

Comment: You're right, I've added a safe way. Anyway, I was adding to the answer my suggestion to not use dictionaries, actually. :)

Comment: Ah, I realize this after your long (nice) addition (+1)! Btw, I'm surprised myself to notice that you can actually use optional chaining as a safe assignment, `testDict1["fireMagic"]?[3] = ["name":"Insane attack","damage":1000, "lvlReq": 60]`, where the expression results in `nil` if key don't exist, or `()` (`Void`) if it does, with the sought (attempted) assignment as a side effect of the latter. That's new, for me!

Comment: Whoa, I always forget that. I'm adding it to my answer. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Merci beaucoup Eric !;)
I was so close to the safe way in Q1... That's so frustrating... I thought I got it all wrong... But Thanks to you, I don't feel the pain anymore :D

Comment: I actually didn't know myself about the optional chaining _assignment_ (only access!) prior to fiddling with it due to this question, so I learning something as well, thanks! It might seem a bit lonely on it's own (as we don't know whether assignments succeeds or not) but useful within say a `guard let _ = ...` (or `if let _ = ...`) clause, as we can perform the assignment directly rather than after the `else` body (e.g. `guard let _ = (testDict1["fireMagic"]?[3] = ["name":"Insane attack","damage":1000, "lvlReq": 60]) else { print("invalid key"); ...; return }`).

Comment: @dfri Thx! There are still plenty of things I need to learn... Wel, that's part of the learning curve. I'll try your suggestions on my project.
Cheers guys.

Comment: @Camelo Happy to help, just note that my comments above snowed into the technical subject of assignments to dictionaries (of unknown key status), whereas for you specific use case, I would recommend the nice 2nd part of EricD:s answer. => for learning, have fun and experiment with many Swift techniques (as nested dictionaries!), but if you're building an actual project, in this case you're probably better of making use of EricD:s struct/enum/array construct above. Happy coding!